# Get current active tab

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium and C#, the Web driver. I want to query the current tab and analyze it for certain things. If useropens new Tab then the new tabs should be queried.

I have been trying all the C# API methods to do this task such as SwitchTo()

```
foreach (string s in this.driver.WindowHandles){
  this.driver.SwitchTo().Window(s);
  if (((IJavaScriptExecutor)this.driver).ExecuteScript("return document.hidden").Equals("false")) {

    IJavaScriptExecutor scriptExe = (IJavaScriptExecutor)this.driver;
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    wait.Until<bool>(Function);//function evaluation certain expression...
    scriptExe.ExecuteScript("alert(\"Something\");");
  }
}
```

Problem with the above code is it flickers between multiple tab as I think is right because I'm switching between the tabs.

Comment: There is no `SwitchTo()` in this code.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've have updated it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the last opened tab you need to use the last window handle instead of iterating over all of them in a loop

```
string windowHandle = this.driver.WindowHandles.Last() // using System.Linq
this.driver.SwitchTo().Window(windowHandle);
//...
```

Comment: but then it won't get to any other tab right?
I want to be able to get a handle to tab which is currently active by the user.

Comment: @BipinGosain For Selenium the active tab is the tab before you opened a new one. To make another tab active you use `SwitchTo()`.

Comment: I understand, Thanks, I actually am just starting out on Selenium. The behaviour I wanted is simple that user can switch between tab on chrome instance and on selenium whatever query I'm running should run on active Tab.